# How to find Confidence of association rule in Apriori algorithm

Tags: associations, data-mining, rules, apriori

I am using Apriori algorithm to identify the frequent item sets of the customer.Based on the identified frequent item sets I want to prompt suggest items to customer when customer adds a new item to his shopping list.Assume my one identified frequent set is [2,3,5].My question is;

if user has already added item 2 and item 5, i want check the confidence of the rule to suggest item 3. for that;

---

confidence = support of (2,3,5)/ support (3) ?

### **OR**

confidence = support of (2,3,5)/ support (2,5)?

---

which equation is correct? please help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the association rule is (2,5) -> (3), than is X = (2,5) and Y = (3). The confidence of an association rule is the support of (X U Y) divided by the support of X. Therefore, the confidence of the association rule is in this case the support of (2,5,3) divided by the support of (2,5).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `A^B -> C` then 
     `Confidence = support(A^B->C)`

i.e. a number of transactions in which all three items are present / support(A,B)

i.e. a number of transactions in which both A and B are present.

So the answer is `confidence= support(2,5,3)/support (2,5)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want  the answer without any explanation:
confidence = support of (2,3,5)/ support (2,5)  in your question is the answer.

Answer (score -2):

What is your **antecedent**?

Stop.treating equarions as black boxes you need to lok up. *understand* them or you will fail.